Astro and Spline
I have a Spline animation that I want to add in Astro but I am not sure how. I don't want to integrate React in order for me to use it. There is a Vanilla JS example but I have a problem importing the component.
I'll share the code export snippet that Spline provides, but I don't know how to integrate it in an existing Astro Component.
import { Application } from '@splinetool/runtime';
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas3d');
const app = new Application(canvas);
app.load('https://prod.spline.design/animation-id/scene.splinecode');


did you npm install it? where do you put the code? please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I've the code above in a <script> tag but of course I cannot access the Application class from splinetool/runtime, I don't know how or whether that is the correct approach.

okay, but you didn't answer the first question. did you npm install @splinetool/runtime ? If so, it should work (see https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/client-side-scripts/)

Of course, I did run npm install @splinetool/runtime. I'll check out the link you pasted.

after you npm install @splinetool/runtime you should be able to use spline like this in your .astro component
<canvas id="canvas3d"></canvas>

<script>
    import { Application } from '@splinetool/runtime';
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas3d');

    if (canvas instanceof HTMLCanvasElement) {
        const app = new Application(canvas);
        app.load('https://prod.spline.design/6Wq1Q7YGyM-iab9i/scene.splinecode');
    } else {
        console.error('Canvas element not found');
    }
</script>

